# Struct, linked list, head,null-pointer, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, null-pointer

How can I define,that the pointer head shows the first linked list element?The compiler shows mistake in the place :

> head=domino->info;

```
struct dominopart {
int number1;
int number2;



};

struct dominoone {
dominopart info;
struct dominoone *next;
};
```

First I defined this as null-pointer,because  the linked list is empty at first.

```
  struct dominoone* next= NULL;
    struct dominoone* head=NULL;
```

Then the information from the file is read line by line.

```
    int readDomino (){
        FILE *datei;


        if((datei=fopen("datei.dat", "r") )==NULL) { 
            std::cout<<"File can't be opened"<<std::endl;
            return 0;
        }else {
            int beginning;
            int temp;
            fscanf(datei, "%d", &beginning);

            for(int i=0; i<beginning; i++) {

                dominoone *domino= new dominoone;
                fscanf(datei, "%i", &temp);
                domino->info.number1=temp;
                fscanf(datei, "%i", &temp);
                domino->info.number2=temp;
                printf("[%d:%d]", domino->info.number1, domino->info.number2);
                domino->next=0;
                 if(i==1) {
                    head=domino->info; //The compiler shows mistake here
                }

           } 
        }return 0;

    }
```

The file is read and shows this,that I have written in the file correctly,but I can't delete the whole list,because my pointer head is still null-pointer:

```
void del () {
    dominoone* tmp;
    while(head != 0) { 
        tmp=(head)->next;
        delete head;
        head=tmp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: `head` is supposed to be a pointer to a `dominoone` structure: `if (i==0) head = domino;`.

Comment: Well, `head` is a `dominoone*` and `domino->info` is a `dominopart`... did you mean `domino->next`?

Comment: "dominopart can not be transformed into dominoone in assignment"

Comment: How is the file being read if there is a compiler error, and the program won't compile?

Comment: When I make the mistakes as commentar.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in this code.

First the assignment `head=domino->info` cannot be performed since the types of the left and right sides are incompatible.

Second, on reading the list of dominos, you need to keep track of the tail of the list.

So you need to declare

```
  struct dominoone* tail=NULL;
```

then after you have populated the structure replace your `if (i==1) ...` with

```
  if (i == 0 ) head = domino;
  else tail->next = domino;
  tail = domino;
```

---

The final version of the `readDomino()` function might look like this:

```
int readDomino (){
        FILE *datei;
        struct dominoone* tail=NULL;


        if((datei=fopen("datei.dat", "r") )==NULL) {
            std::cout<<"File can't be opened"<<std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        int list_size;
        fscanf(datei, "%d", &list_size);

        for(int i=0; i<list_size; i++) {
                dominoone *domino= new dominoone;
                fscanf(datei, "%i", &domino->info.number1);
                fscanf(datei, "%i", &domino->info.number2);
                printf("[%d:%d]\n",
                       domino->info.number1, 
                       domino->info.number2);
                domino->next=NULL;

                if (i == 0 ) head = domino;
                else tail->next = domino;
                tail = domino;
           }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva works for me ... Updated the post with a complete listing of readDomino() for your reference.